# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This block of code is getting the error:

```
type Types = {
    foo: (s: string, n: number) => void
    bar: () => void
}
type AbstractType = Record<string, any>

class Class1<GenericType extends AbstractType> {
    public method<T extends keyof GenericType>(event: T, ...data: Parameters<GenericType[T]>) {}
}

class Class2<GenericType extends AbstractType> extends Class1<GenericType & Types> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // error: Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<(GenericType & Types)["bar"]>'.
        this.method('bar')
    }
}
```

Can someone help to fix the TS error:

```
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<(GenericType & Types)["bar"]>'.
```

works great if Class2 pass `AbstractType` instead of `GenericType` to Class1

```
class Class2<GenericType extends AbstractType> extends Class1<AbstractType & Types> {}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oG8BQBIAZgezwC4oAKBYhYAJwEsA7AcwBoo7i6BXAWwCMIqAlCgB8UAG54aAE2w8AhlWIkhyUROkYAvhlCQoAQR6UqcgMbA4e1ACUIpvFSkAeY-WZQ5dEMIwZTAGzkEJABhQOCARicAcQg6fhpTS2gIAA9gOKkkQ2MzC3hRTCwwDh5-RKguCGAACzxnGCg0jLosqABrCBA8HChY%20NokgpIIMTjgYhgWADpZqTlgOWIABQU5KoyqBBi4hKHIAG0YAF1hITRtbT9w0JuAJh2BxOSm9Mzso2o85NFm96gwkEEFF%20nsXgAyWDwBCFbD2OjGDjmBzKdDYLAIDiQKjKDBQfEE-EAeiJTSoVAcxH0VAY3HGUB6UF00AA5AdjiyoDQkHQ8MAPMEaAw6HIytBgHgoGA1ht%20AzesyoCzViZZVsnCRQYMIVDIAgBAcAETyKiG04s6bo2rc6YbOpSEgsk0sgTYS4YIA)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty array in class1 like this to solve this issue

```
class Class1<GenericType extends AbstractType> {
    public method<T extends keyof GenericType>(event: T, ...data: Parameters<GenericType[T]> | []) {}
}
```

Comment: then `this.method('foo')` is going to work, altho `s` & `n` arguments are required